# Why 'Undefined EVIRONMENT' in db_debug codeigniter4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php, codeigniter-4, php-8.2

Can anyone help me,please
i just try codeigniter4,and when i confirg database, db_debug always error because undefined ENVIRONMENT but i know this code actually true

i've read the documentation and reinstall the composer and codeigniter, that doesn't work

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and the exact error message. Is this problem only occuring when using PHP 8.2? How is it related to Composer?

Comment: Have you defined a `.env` file at the root of your project directory?